# Is it possible to render only a specific slide number using Beamer?

Tags: beamer

Suppose I am working on a frame which contains heavy use of `\visible` and friends, e.g. something of the form

```
\begin{frame}
\visible<1->{ ... }
\visible<2->{ ... }
\visible<3->{ ... }
...
\visible<20->{ ... }
\end{frame}
```

When editing such a frame, I have to wait for all slides to render before I can see the effect of a change. For TiKZ-heavy code, that can take a while. Is it possible to easily render only a single slide number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does

```
\begin{frame}<3>
\visible<1->{ ... }
\visible<2->{ ... }
\visible<3->{ ... }
...
\visible<20->{ ... }
\end{frame}
```

work? If not, please add an example that shows the time effect.

Comment: That works exactly as I wanted it - thanks!

Comment: This doesn't compile for me, but ``\begin{frame}<3>`` works.

Comment: @PeterKoepernik Fixed! Thanks for spotting the typo